# Android - SyncAdapater addPeriodicSync

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, periodic-task

I implemented a periodic sync which runs every hour, it works when app is launched in background but when I kill app from multitasks list, periodic sync is not yet running every hour.
Is the periodic sync should going to run even if the app is not running in background?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, periodic sync is run even if app is killed. It's my custom process which failed if app is killed.